# Alternative methods for an integer variable to be multiplied by a number in c

Tags: c

In how many ways a variable can be multiplied by 8 in a c program ? I know

```
1. a*8
2. a<<8 ?
```

Are there any more alternative ways ?Its a technical aptitude test question.

Comment: I wouldn't call `a << 8` to be "an integer variable multiplied by a number" because that statement is very generic, while bit shifting is very specific. Also, that shift doesn't multiply by 8, it shifts by 8 (multiplies by 2^8)... a<<3 would multiply by 8.

Comment: `a*8` != `a<<8`. It's `a<<3`. How about `a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a` for an answer?

Comment: `a<<3` multiplies with `8`.

Comment: Also what is the type of `a`? `double`? `unsigned long int`? ...

Comment: @mah ..yeah sorry! its by mistake that i wrote a<<8. it should be a<<3.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes! that is right too.

Comment: @pmg The type of a is signed int. but would that make any difference?

Comment: @user24632 a method to multiply by 8 that works on [IEEE numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is to add 3 to the exponent.

Comment: if the value were a double, my compiler (clang-500.0.68) won't allow the shift... and if the compiler did allow the shift, the results would not be the same as an int shift.

Comment: @mah your's was helpful too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a<<8` is not the same as `a * 8`.

`a<<1` is equivalent to `a*2`.
`a<<2` is equivalent to `a*4`.
`a<<3` is equivalent to `a*8`.
`a<<8` is equivalent to `a*256`.

If you really want other ways, some pedantic stuff:

```
a+a+a+a + a+a+a+a
a<<1 + a<<1 + a<<1 + a<<1
a<<2 * 2
2*(a<<1 + a<<1)
2*(a<<1)*2
a*2*2*2
a*(2<<2)
a*(4<<1)
```

Comment: yes sorry ! it was by mistake that i wrote a<<8. it should be a<<3.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to itself by 7 times, since

8 * a

is equal to

a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a "variable", you need to think about the type of that variable also.

Bit shifts will only work on unsigned variables or signed variables provided the value isn't negative, and even some of these may fail if the number is high enough that multiplying it by 8 will overflow the target variable's data type. Your bit shifts generally won't work on floating point either.

I like some of the answer above though, made me chuckle :-)